# java generic class hierarchy and generic implementation

Tags: java, generics

This probably is stupid question, but I am not able to understand why the below compilation is failing.

My class hierarchy

```
Dao.java

public interface Dao<E extends Entity, S extends SearchCriteria> {
    <E> E create(E e) throws Exception;
}
```

There is a generic implementation of this Dao

```
DaoImpl.java

public abstract class DaoImpl<E extends Entity, S extends SearchCriteria> implements Dao<E, S> {
    @Override
    public <E> E create(E e) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("this operation is not supported");
    }
}
```

And then there is specialized implementation

```
ProcessDaoImpl.java

public class ProcessDaoImpl extends DaoImpl<Process, WildcardSearchCriteria> {
    @Override // this is where compilation is failing, I get the error that create doesn't override a superclass method
    public Process create(Process entity) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Description of entity class hierarchy

```
Process.java

public class Process extends AuditEntity {
    // some pojo fields
}

AuditEntity.java

public abstract class AuditEntity extends IdentifiableEntity {
    // some pojo fields
}

IdentifiableEntity.java

public abstract class IdentifiableEntity extends Entity {
    // some pojo fields
}

Entity.java

public abstract class Entity implements Serializable {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you should declare in the interface and the abstract class, the  `E create(E e)` method without `<E>` at the beginning otherwise you don't refer to the `E` of the declared type in the class but to a `E` type defining in the scope of the method :

Replace :

```
 public interface Dao<E extends Entity, S extends SearchCriteria> {
    <E> E create(E e) throws Exception;
}
```

by

```
public interface Dao<E extends Entity, S extends SearchCriteria> {
     E create(E e) throws Exception;
}
```

and replace that :

```
@Override
public <E> E create(E e) throws Exception {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("this operation is not supported");
}
```

by :

```
@Override
public E create(E e) throws Exception {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("this operation is not supported");
}
```

Comment: My bad, that was pretty novice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is:

```
<E> E create(E e) throws Exception;
```

This `E` is not the same `E` as the one in the class declaration. You are declaring a *new* type parameter that has the name `E`, is not bounded, and shadows the outer `E` from the class.

Change it to

```
E create(E e) throws Exception;
```